# Placing a twitter bootstrap tooltip on the right side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a tooltip using twitter bootstrap in rails. The tooltip is to be displayed on page load. So for doing this I have added the following in my markup of the field:

```
rel="tooltip" title="Press CTRL+C To Copy"
```

And then I have added the following code into my application.js file:

```
window.onload = function(){
var text_input = document.getElementById ('url_copy');
text_input.focus ();
text_input.select ();
$('#url_copy').tooltip('show')
}
```

Fortunately it's displaying the tooltip. Nut unfortunately it's displaying it on the top. But I want to place it on right. I know I have to use a placement: 'right' or something like that as mentioned http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

But how should the code exactly look like??

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: `.tooltip({placement: 'right'});`

Comment: Ya, It's showing on the right side...But as I'm deleting the 'show' here so the tooltip isn't displayed on page load, it's being fired on mouseover on the text field...But I have to show it on pageload..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the page that you linked it shows you examples.

To place it on the right use the following html.

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</a>
```

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: I'm wondering is it possible to change the display of the tooltop box little larger??

Comment: You can override the default bootstrap CSS and set large dimensions in your CSS.